# Insert empty rows to keep indices consistent in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have this table in R:

```
testTable=data.frame(c(1:5,7:10,12:20))
```

Which looks like this (where 1., 2., etc. are the row numbers of the table):

```
testTable

 1.  1
 2.  2
 3.  3
 4.  4
 5.  5
 6.  7
 7.  8
 8.  9
 9.  10
 10. 12
 11. 13
 12. 14
 13. 15
 14. 16
 15. 17
 16. 18
 17. 19
 18. 20
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
testTable

 1.  1
 2.  2
 3.  3
 4.  4
 5.  5
 6.  NA
 7.  7
 8.  8
 9.  9
 10. 10
 11. NA
 12. 12
 13. 13
 14. 14
 15. 15
 16. 16
 17. 17
 18. 18
 19. 19
 20. 20
```

I.e., I want to keep the row number to match the number in the first column, and if that number isn't in my original dataset, I want to fill the first column with "NA." Is there a way to do this in R without a loop?

Thanks! (And apologies for the format...I couldn't figure out how to make the columns appear side-by-side without using a numbered list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bunch of ways to do this. Here's one.

```
# dummy data
d <- data.frame(x=1:20)[sort(sample(20, 15)), , drop=FALSE]
row.names(d) <- seq_len(nrow(d))

d

#     x
# 1   1
# 2   4
# 3   6
# 4   7
# 5   9
# 6  10
# 7  11
# 8  12
# 9  13
# 10 14
# 11 15
# 12 16
# 13 17
# 14 18
# 15 19 


d2 <- data.frame(x=seq_len(max(d$x)))
d2$x[setdiff(d2$x, d$x)] <- NA
```

We create a second data.frame, `d2`, with number of rows equal to the maximum value observed in `d`. This contains a column with an integer sequence from 1 to the number of rows. Then we fill with NAs all the positions that shouldn't have values (i.e. those that are in `d2$x` but not in `d$x`).

Not very elegant, but it gets the job done.

```
d2

#     x
# 1   1
# 2  NA
# 3  NA
# 4   4
# 5  NA
# 6   6
# 7   7
# 8  NA
# 9   9
# 10 10
# 11 11
# 12 12
# 13 13
# 14 14
# 15 15
# 16 16
# 17 17
# 18 18
# 19 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach to do it. I add another column `sampledata` to the original data.frame for illustration.

```
require(dplyr)

testTable <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,7:10,12:20), sampledata = runif(18))

new.df <- data.frame(x = sapply(1:20, function(y) ifelse(y %in% testTable$x, y, NA)))

left_join(new.df, testTable, by="x")

#    x sampledata
#1   1      0.937
#2   2      0.657
#3   3      0.568
#4   4      0.029
#5   5      0.094
#6  NA         NA
#7   7      0.820
#8   8      0.111
#9   9      0.979
#10 10      0.135
#11 NA         NA
#12 12      0.154
#13 13      0.531
#14 14      0.897
#15 15      0.595
#16 16      0.243
#17 17      0.370
#18 18      0.544
#19 19      0.146
#20 20      0.793
```

There are probably more elegant ways to do it without creating a new data.frame.

I use `left_join` from `dplyr` because it seems to keep the order in the joined data.frame, whereas `merge` seems to order all NA entries at the bottom.